# Can anyone help me with this?

Tags: activecollab

I need help with generating an api key for my self hosted install.

If someone could walk me through via video how to get an api key for my self hosted install, that would be great.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a brief instruction for issuing tokens: https://blog.activecollab.com/labs/2016/02/12/active-collab-api-wrapper-3.html

and here is the full API documentation: https://developers.activecollab.com/api-documentation/